# How to get values from a delimited string?

Tags: java, string, split

I have a delimited string and The delimiter is "$%". The fields are in an specific order. For example: John$%Smith$%30$%Los Angeles
I need to get the values of this string and store them in the respective property

```
Customer.firstName(_)
Customer.lastName(_)
Customer.age(_)
Customer.city(_)
```

So far I have tried this but I know I am doing it incorrectly:

```
if(thisString != null){
        if(thisString.endsWith("$%")){
            Customer.firstName(thisString.substring(0,indexOf("$%");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just split using your delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

Trying using Java's [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

For example:

```
//Split string based on "$%"
String[] values = thisString.split(Pattern.quote("$%"));
Customer.firstName() = values[0]; //Set first name equal to first string from the split
//etc
```